# Dropbox-Daemon crashes after renaming username

Tags: linux-mint, rename, dropbox

After I renamed my username in Linux Mint as described in this
[article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558669/renaming-user-name),
my Dropbox-Daemon allways crushes.

Done renaming process:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
~$ exec sudo -i
~$ killall -u oldname
~$ id oldname
~$ usermod -l newname oldname
~$ groupmod -n newname oldname
~$ usermod -d /home/newname -m newname
~$ usermod -c "New_real_name" newname
~$ id newname
~$ reboot
```

In my case:

```
~$ exec sudo -i
~$ killall -u user
~$ id user
~$ usermod -l yuza user
~$ groupmod -n yuza user
~$ usermod -d /home/yuza -m yuza
~$ usermod -c "Orthonym" yuza
~$ id yuza
~$ reboot
```

I reinstalled the Dropbox-Daemon and every time I try to start the Deamon it
crushes and produces allways a different dropbox_error####.txt-file.

```
~$ sudo apt remove dropbox
~$ sudo apt install dropbox
~$ dropbox status
   Dropbox isn't running!
~$ sudo dropbox start -i
```

**Pop-up:**

[image: Dropbox crash pop-up]

**Error report:** dropbox_error7_MXjP.txt

```
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 39.4.49
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
machine_id: failed
pid: 8571
ppid: 8570
ppid exe: '/usr/bin/python2.7'
uid: 1000
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='yuza', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Orthonym', pw_dir='/home/yuza', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='yuza', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='Orthonym', pw_dir='/home/yuza', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 1000
gid: 1000
egid: 1000
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='yuza', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='yuza', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: '/home/yuza'
     real_path='/home/yuza'
            mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
     parent mode=040755 uid=0   gid=0
HOME: u'/home/yuza'
appdata: u'/home/user/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path=u'/home/user/.dropbox/instance1'
                not found
         parent not found
dropbox_path: u'/home/yuza/Dropbox'
              real_path=u'/home/yuza/Dropbox'
                        not found
              parent    mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
sys_executable: '/home/yuza/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-39.4.49/dropbox'
                real_path='/home/yuza/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-39.4.49/dropbox'
                        mode=0100755    uid=1000    gid=1000
                parent  mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
trace.__file__: '/home/yuza/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-39.4.49/python-packages-27.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                real_path='/home/yuza/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-39.4.49/python-packages-27.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: '/tmp'
         real_path='/tmp'
                mode=041777 uid=0   gid=0
         parent mode=040755 uid=0   gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 6196, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 2412, in run
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 1453, in startup_low
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 1035, in safe_makedirs
  File "os.pyc", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.pyc", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.pyc", line 157, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user'
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this mess?
I am grateful for any help, links, references and hints!

Answer (score 0):

You say you re-installed the dropbox daemon, yet it still refers to /home/user/.dropbox/instance1. Perhaps you did not un-install, and therefore have some leftover configs?

You might fix it with a symlink, so /home/user/.dropbox points at /home/yuza/.dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

@J_H you were right, although I uninstalled dropbox I ran the command 
`~$ locate dropbox` and saw that there were many files remaining. So I 
deletet many of them (see commands below) and finally it worked, after 
I installed it again!

```
~$ sudo apt remove dropbox
~$ locate dropbox
~$ rm -rfv /home/yuza/.dropbox
~$ rm -rfv /home/yuza/.dropbox-dist
~$ sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/status/*/*dropbox*
~$ sudo rm -rfv /usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/*/*dropbox*
~$ sudo rm -rfv /home/yuza/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/storage/default/*dropbox*
~$ sudo apt install dropbox
~$ dropbox start -i
~$ dropbox status
```